# How To Summarize Results and Display in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table, inventory. The items in inventory have an item ID, but there might be multiple entries with different colors and sizes for the same item id. I'm trying to figure out how to return the total number in inventory for each item. So, I would return the total number of item 1, and not the total number of yellow item 1's then the total number of small item 1's, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: You should edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic query would be an aggregation query, something like:

```
select itemid, sum(quantity)
from inventory
group by itemid;
```

If you want the total for a single item, then you would add something like `where itemid = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, it sounds like you need to use `distinct` with `count`:

```
select count(distinct itemid)
from inventory
```

Depending on your desired results, you may be looking to group your results.  In which case, you'd use `group by` with the desired field.  Maybe something like this:

```
select itemid, count(*)
from inventory
group by itemid
```

This will return a row with the count of records per item id.